# SwiftUI Unable to change the color of my SF Symbol Image in my Button

Tags: swiftui

I dont know if it has something to do with the toolbar modifer or what. The current image color is blue and i want it to change to black. Help

```
               ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
                            Button(action: {
                                
                            }, label: {
                                Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                                    .renderingMode(.template)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    
                            })
                        }
                }
```

Comment: Move your modifiers from the image to the button. All buttons will have a default to `.blue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `.accentColor(.black)` modifier on your `NavigationView`

Answer (score 0):

Try .renderingMode(.original)?  Should make it default black.

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
                            Button(action: {
                                
                            }, label: {
                                Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                                    .renderingMode(.original)
                            })
                        }
                }
```